# jquery select by attribute name each this value pepend text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes, each, prepend

Select elements by a certain attribute name, in this case "icon":

```
<a href="#" icon="one.png">link</a>
<a href="#" icon="two.png">link</a>
<a href="#" icon="three.png">link</a>
```

Then to each element, prepend a `<span>` with text of the element attribute value,
example:

```
<span>one.png</span><a href="#" icon="one.png">link</a>
<span>two.png</span><a href="#" icon="two.png">link</a>
<span>three.png</span><a href="#" icon="three.png">link</a>
```

How to do it?

Comment: and what have you tried???

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.before()` with a receiver function to accomplish your task,

```
$('a[icon]').before(function(){
  return $("<span>", {text: $(this).attr('icon')});
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/g22Rw/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('a[icon]').each(function(){
   $(this).before('<span>'+$(this).attr('icon')+'</span>');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cYNL9/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$('a[icon]').each(function(){
   $(this).before('<span>'+$(this).attr('icon')+'</span>') 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J2QVN/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a[icon]').each(function(){
   $('<span />', { text : this.getAttribute('icon') }).insertBefore(this);
});
```

Comment: @downvoter care to comment, this was a rookie mistake to use `.before()` method that has to be `.insertBefore()`. Updated.